# Python MyHashTable class: search method with linear probing

Tags: python, class, hashtable, linear-probing

I need help implementing a method for my "MyHashTable" class:

```
def search(self, search_key):
```

The method is supposed to use linear probing to handle collision resolution. If the search_key is in the hash table then the method returns the slot number of the slot containing that search_key. If the search_key is not in the hash table, the method returns -1

My class looks like this:

```
class MyHashTable:

def __init__(self, capacity):
    self.capacity = capacity
    self.slots = [None] * self.capacity

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.slots )

def __len__(self):
    count = 0
    for i in self.slots:
        if i != None:
            count += 1
    return count

def hash_function(self, key):
    i = key % self.capacity
    return i

def insert(self, key):
    slot = self.hash_function(key)
    orig = slot
    while True:
        if self.slots[slot] is None:
            self.slots[slot] = key
            return slot

        if self.slots[slot] == key:
            return -2

        slot = (slot + 1) % self.capacity
        if slot == orig:
            return -1

def search(self, search_key):
```

Any help or tutorial links would be awesome. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only using a single list to store all the values, if you wanted a hash table you might use a list of lists where each list was a bucket but if you just want to check if the element is in your hash table with your own code:

```
def search(self, search_key):
    hsh = self.hash_function(search_key)
    if self.slots[hsh] is None:
        return -1
    while hsh < self.capacity:
        if self.slots[hsh] == search_key:
            return hsh
        hsh += 1
    return -1
```

You also have to handle the case where you have multiple collisions so we need at worst to check every element in the hash table to find the correct value:

```
 def search(self, search_key):
    hsh = self.hash_function(search_key)
    if self.slots[hsh] is None:
        return -1
    for i in range(self.capacity):
        mod = (hsh + i) % self.capacity
        if self.slots[mod] == search_key:
            return mod
    return -1
```

The first while loop will probe one value over at a time but if we have wrapped around the list from multiple collisions it would miss elements at the start so  using  `range` and `mod = (hsh + i) % self.capacity` makes sure we check all entries like the example below.

```
m = MyHashTable(5)

m.insert(13) # 13 % 5 = 3
m.insert(73) # 83 % 5 = 3
m.insert(93) # 93 & 5 = 3
print(m.search(13)) # 3
print(m.search(73)) # 4
print(m.search(93)) # 0
print(m.search(2)) # -1
```

You can make your len method `O(1)` by keeping track of when you add a unique value to your hash table, there is also a nice wiki page on [Open_addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing) parts of which you can adopt into your code and it will help you create a proper mapping of keys to values and resized your hash table when needed. If you want to store more than just numbers you need to use a different hash function, I just use hash but you can use whatever you like. Also using `in` when your hash table is full and the key does not exist will cause an infinite loop so you will need to handle that case:

```
class MyHashTable:
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.slots = [None] * self.capacity
        self.count = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.slots)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return self.search(item) != -1

    def __len__(self):
        return self.count

    def hash_function(self, key):
        return hash(key) % self.capacity

    def find_slot(self, key):
        slot = self.hash_function(key)
        while self.slots[slot] is not None and self.slots[slot] != key:
            slot = (slot + 1) % self.capacity
        return slot

    def insert(self, key):
        slot = self.find_slot(key)
        if self.slots[slot] != key:
            self.slots[slot] = key
            self.count += 1

    def search(self, key):
        i = self.find_slot(key)
        if self.slots[i] is not None:  
            return i
        return -1
```

Add a `__contains__` will also allow you to use `in` to test for membership:

```
m = MyHashTable(5)

m.insert("foo")
m.insert(73)
m.insert(93)
m.insert(1)
print(m.search(73))
print(m.search(93))
print(m.search(1))
print(m.search("foo"))
m.insert(73)
print(m.slots)
print(len(m))
print("foo" in m)
print(5 in m)
```

Output:

```
3
4
1
0
['foo', 1, None, 73, 93]
4
True
False
```